# Scroll between separate .html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

A lot of scroll jquery plugins work like this:
http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/page-scroll-to-id/demo/demo.html
and
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

They scroll between sections.

Questions:
Are there also plugins or solution that scroll between .html pages:

- up (when reached the top it scrolls to the previous page) and
- down (when reached the bottom it scrolls to the next page)

Example but not working like I want:

http://vostrel.cz/so/9652944/page.html

It uses these codes:

```
(function($){

var jump=function(e)
{
   if (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var target = $(this).attr("href");
   }else{
       var target = location.hash;
   }

   $('html,body').animate(
   {
       scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
   },1000,function()
   {
       location.hash = target;
   });

}

$('html, body').hide()

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

    if (location.hash){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show()
            jump()
        }, 0);
    }else{
      $('html, body').show()
    }
});

})(jQuery)
```

See it working here:
http://vostrel.cz/so/9652944/page.html

But it misses (A) when reached the top scroll on page 1 and (B) when reached the bottom scroll on page 2 and (C) when scrolling up scroll upwards, when scrolling down scroll downwards. The example always scrolls in the same direction and that's also a problem.

The above codes are just an example. Maybe someone has much better codes. Main intention is to make my idea clear. Hope this illustrates what I want to achieve. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Post the code here, not just a link

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask a question...

Comment: As @CBroe mentions, this seems like a terrible idea. If you are developing your own web browser, maybe you could use this as an UI idea, but in real life this will annoy the sh*t out of people. People scroll up and down pages because of Fitt's Law - and you would completely break that.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's an annoying feature. I personally don't care for the affect, but I've seen several professional sites that do it quite well. Cinzel, the idea behind it is using AJAX to load pages after a certain trigger (such as reaching the top/bottom of the page). This has lots of good applications, like reading a long-form book.

Comment: @philtune There is certainly a different expectancy when reading a book than when navigating a website, but it still sounds bad. If I read a book, I want to be able to scroll up to the table of contents because I know its at the start. This system would never be fast enough anyhow... I think it is an awful idea, but I admit that there might be some _very_ specific usecases :)

Comment: @somethinghere Yeah, exactly my point, there are specific use cases. I would never read a book on a website anyways when I have eReaders all over my house. But look into some user testing to see if this is really something beneficial or just something you think is cool. Valid question, though.

Comment: consider Angular.js?

Comment: The effect of scrolling up and down is used by Google, Sony, British Airways (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#who-is-using-fullpagejs). I want to use the same scrolling effect. Instead of reaching the top or bottom the trigger to scroll can also be a next / previous page button or just a scroll bar. That's not the point. The point is how to replace sections for .html pages? Any smart guys here?

Comment: thank you jilykate. Do you have a specific link to this feature within Angular.js that leads to this scroll effect?

Answer (score 0):

In horizontal scroll (swipe) direction (or it could be changed in vertical direction if you like) it could be done this way:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="city" class="demo-page" data-dom-cache="true" data-theme="a" data-prev="prevCity" data-next="nextCity" data-url="city">
<!-- "city", "prevCity" and "nextCity" are used as placeholders and contain the name of the applicable city in our demo files. -->
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" data-id="hdr" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h1>City</h1>
    <a href="swipe-page.html" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-icon-shadow="false">Back</a>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="trivia-city" class="trivia ui-content" data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" data-tolerance="50,30,30,30" data-theme="d">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        <p>Here some text.</p>
    </div><!-- /popup -->
</div><!-- /content -->
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" data-id="ftr" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" class="control ui-btn-left" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <a href="#" class="prev" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="next" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d">Next</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#trivia-city" data-rel="popup" class="trivia-btn ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="d" data-mini="true">Trivia</a>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

JS:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "[data-role='page'].demo-page", function() {
var page = "#" + $( this ).attr( "id" ),
    // Get the filename of the next page that we stored in the data-next attribute
    next = $( this ).jqmData( "next" ),
    // Get the filename of the previous page that we stored in the data-prev attribute
    prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );
// Check if we did set the data-next attribute
if ( next ) {
    // Prefetch the next page
    $.mobile.loadPage( next + ".html" );
    // Navigate to next page on swipe left
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft", page, function() {
        $.mobile.changePage( next + ".html", { transition: "slide" });
    });
    // Navigate to next page when the "next" button is clicked
    $( ".control .next", page ).on( "click", function() {
        $.mobile.changePage( next + ".html", { transition: "slide" } );
    });
}
// Disable the "next" button if there is no next page
else {
    $( ".control .next", page ).addClass( "ui-disabled" );
}
// The same for the previous page (we set data-dom-cache="true" so there is no need to prefetch)
if ( prev ) {
    $( document ).on( "swiperight", page, function() {
        $.mobile.changePage( prev + ".html", { transition: "slide", reverse: true } );
    });
    $( ".control .prev", page ).on( "click", function() {
        $.mobile.changePage( prev + ".html", { transition: "slide", reverse: true } );
    });
}
else {
    $( ".control .prev", page ).addClass( "ui-disabled" );
}
```

});

CSS:

```
/* Set the background image sources */
#newyork { background-image: url(../../_assets/img/newyork.jpg); }
#buenosaires { background-image: url(../../_assets/img/buenosaires.jpg); }
#paris { background-image: url(../../_assets/img/paris.jpg); }
#capetown { background-image: url(../../_assets/img/capetown.jpg); }
#seoul { background-image: url(../../_assets/img/seoul.jpg); }
#sydney { background-image: url(../../_assets/img/sydney.jpg); }
/* Background settings */
.demo-page {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* Transparent footer */
.demo-page .ui-footer {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    bottom: 0;
}
/* The footer won't have a height because there are only two absolute positioned elements in it.
So we position the buttons from the bottom. */
.control.ui-btn-left, .trivia-btn.ui-btn-right {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 7px;
    margin: 0;
}
/* Custom styling for the trivia source */
small {
    font-size: .75em;
    color: #666;
}
/* Prevent text selection while swiping with mouse */
.demo-page .ui-header, .ui-title, .control .ui-btn, .trivia-btn {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

DEMO:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/swipe/newyork.html

DOCUMENTATION:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/swipe/swipe-page.html